# Shortcuts app: Copy/paste text with altered formatting

Tags: copy-paste, shortcuts-app, formatting

I have what seems like a simple problem.  I'd like to copy an article from the News App and paste a well-formatted version into an email.  This works sometimes, but some articles end up formatted horribly.  What I'd like to do is: (a) change the font from Helvetica to Times and (b) make a blank line between all paragraphs.

What I have tried so far is a script that:

1. Get Clipboard
2. Make HTML from clipboard
3. Set Variable HTMLcontents = HTML result
4. Replace "Helvetica" with "Times" in the result.

Then it breaks.  I've tried everything I can think of.  What I need is to replace the `<\p>` tag with `<\p><br>`.  Cannot get this to happen.

I believe that this script would work perfectly (adding:  Make RTF from HTML) if I could get this to work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you want help with AppleScript you will need to paste the whole thing into your question. Otherwise the AppleScript gurus 'round here won't know what to look for.